# How to Create a Fixed Footer In WinUI3?

Tags: c#, xaml, footer, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

Gys I have been trying to create a fixed footer at the bottom of the page using WinUi-3. I dont know how to do it can anyone help me. Please give me a code example.

Comment: Do you mean you want a window that has a page and a footer?

Comment: yes can you help me out with an example ...

Comment: There is also a [WinUI-Gallery](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/220426eaae00523472b0fd4f2a25c17cb232522d/WinUIGallery/ControlPagesSampleCode/Motion/ConnectedAnimation/ConnectedAnimationSample1_xaml.txt#L46) sample you can refer to. And does @AndrewKeepCoding 's answer work for you?

Comment: I didn't get chance to check it my PC broke I am gonna check it today thank you sir. Can you tell me the name of that example in win UI gallery.

Comment: [This detail page](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/220426eaae00523472b0fd4f2a25c17cb232522d/WinUIGallery/ConnectedAnimationPages/DetailedInfoPage.xaml) of the *ConnectedAnimation* example has the same XAML layout as what you want. Or you can refer to @AndrewKeepCoding 's answer.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT thank you sir for your help, Andrew's code worked fine for me, I will take a look at what you gave me too thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your window you could:

```xml
<Window
...
>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PageFrame" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <!-- Your footer here. -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

then set your pages as *PageFrame*'s `Content`.